# In C: comparing arrays with both string and integer elements

Tags: c, arrays

In C : I wrote a function which checks if a sub-array, `arr2`, of type `int` exists ‘as-is’ in an array, `arr1`, of the same type. It returns 1 if all the elements of `arr2` are found in `arr1` in exactly the same order and it returns 0 otherwise. The function seems to work fine but I have two questions:

**Q1**: What if we want to do the same with mixed types of elements in both arrays, especially if we don’t know in advance what types of elements will be used and in what order? By that I mean that both the type of each element and the order of their appearance must be left to the user’s discretion. I have read a lot of similar Q&A but I am still quite unclear about the solution.

**Q2**: Consider the following example:

```
int arr1[] = {34, 231, "not the declared type..", "..recognized nevertheless", 3, 7};

int arr2[] = {231, "not the declared type..", "..recognized nevertheless"};
```

Why does my function actually work (for example returning 1 in the above case)? I thought it should fail -since the elements used are not of the declared type (`int`)- or even worse that I would get a compiler error. On the contrary it seems to succeed as it recognizes and compares aptly even the last full stop or capital letter. Well, it does fail with floats (I guess it converts them to integers and compares only the integer part?) but why does it alright in the other cases? Does it convert the strings too, and what kind of conversion takes place?

I am very new to both C and the forum so please forgive the ignorance.

Comment: you cannot put string/char array as element into int array, probably you're putting pointers, which are the same

Comment: The compiler should have answered your question with a warning, even with warnings set to the lowest level.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Did it not print any warnings? Unless you *really* know what you're doing, you should treat C compiler warnings as if they were fatal errors.

Comment: Yes, that is what I expected: a warning. But as I said, there are no warnings and  furthermore it compares correctly the arrays!

Comment: You need to look at the build output window to see the warnings.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays in c are *homogenous*, that is, all elements are the same type. The example you describe:

```
int arr1[] = {34, 231, "not the declared type..", "..recognized nevertheless", 3, 7};
```

is invalid code. The initializers must all be `int`, (or expressions implicitly convertible to `int`).

If your compiler does not produce a diagnostic message for this code, then you need to turn up the warning level on your compiler.

Some compilers may, as a non-standard extension, convert the string to an integer representing the memory address of the first character of the string.  But the C Standard says that they must output a diagnostic message while doing so.

Comment: As I said, I thought it was invalid code, and that is why I am asking this. I don't know how to turn up the compiler's warning level. I am a beginner using Microsoft Studio 2015. If the compiler converted the string just to the address of the first character of the string then why it recognizes the differences in the rest of the characters?

Comment: @spra if you use the same string literal twice in your program then the compiler may decide to only allocate one copy of the literal  , so in your test code if you used the same string in two different arrays then both could convert to the same integer.   (This could also happen if the literals were different lengths but coincided on the tail)

Comment: Make sure you are actually checking VS's build output window to see if there are any messages

Answer (score 0):

> Why does my function actually work?

The trick is that in C, you *can* do this, but the results certainly will not reliably  meet OP's needs.

```
int arr1[] = {34, 231, "not the declared type..", "..recognized nevertheless", 3, 7};

int arr2[] = {231, "not the declared type..", "..recognized nevertheless"};
```

As list initializers to an `int` array, each string literal, like `"not the declared type.."`, converts to the address of the first element: a `char *`.  Since the array expects `int`, a `char *` to `int` conversion occurs, which should generate a *warning*.  It is technically allowed, but not recommended.  The conversion of `char *` to `int` itself is a problem.  The rare cases when pointer to integer conversion makes some sense, it "should" be a conversion to `void *`, then to an optionally supported special sized integer of type  `intptr_t`.  That integer type is wide enough to round trip back to a valid pointer.  `int` may not be wide enough.

The conversion to `int` may lose information, so the result may now be a hash code of the pointer (e.g. its lowest 32-bits).  Even two string literals of the same content may or may not convert to the same `int` as the may or may not exist in the same place.  Two string literals may convert to the same `int`, yet have different content - hash collision.  Things may appear to works - but not portably/reliably.

Story Time's end: C allows OP a lot of rope, more than enough to hang the program.  There is no safety net here.

Comment: Yes, from the this one and the above answers what I understand is that it may or may not succeed because of unsafe conversions. I had no real intention to use such an unreasonable syntax in the first place. I just wanted to understand. Quite helpful answers.

Comment: It is not so much "unsafe" as there may be no dreaded "undefined behavior" (UB).  It is just that the results are not that useful. So subsequent code would be unsafe if it relied on this.  IMO, a good +1 post.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to my second question and it was the (circumvention of the) debugger, indeed: In order to stop the console window from closing I kept using the Control+F5 shortcut which I now realized that it runs the application without the debugger. I just tried with just F5 and there were errors (not very helpful to me anyway) although the program still ran successfully. However I still don't get how this is possible. I thought that there are just two cases: either a syntax is correct in a language or incorrect. This is obviously incorrect. Why does it succeed with what it is doing?

My first question is still valid, too. Thanks.

Comment: What I understand from the above answers is that it could be done with not always predictable results and thus it is unsafe.